# Bash: Read commands from file

Tags: linux, bash, sed, grep

I'm using a minimal netinstall image of Debian. Here is my script to start my user processes and daemons at the first login. It reads a file consisting of commands line by line, checks if they are running already and launches them, if not:

```
#!/bin/bash
## This script reads a list of user startup daemons and launches them after the first login

STAT=`who | grep "$USER" | wc -l` ## Get login count
if [ "$STAT" -eq 1 ] ; then ## If login shell
  while IFS=' ' read line  ## First attempt to separate fields fails
  do
    CMD=`echo "$line" | grep -v ^\#` ## Use non comment lines only
    if [ -n "$CMD" ] ; then
      eval set "$CMD" ## The actual field separation
      APPID=$(pgrep "$1")&& ## Check if process $1 of $CMD is already active and launch it if not
        (echo "$1 already active as "$APPID) || ("$@" 1>/dev/null&& echo "Started $1 as $(pgrep "$1")")
    fi
  done < ~/.scripts/daemons
  echo "start-daemons: Finished"
else
  echo "start-daemons: Not a login shell"
fi
```

The file of commands `~/.scripts/daemons` looks as following:

```
## List of processes / daemons to start at user login
## <command> <argument1> <argument2> ..
mpd
pulseaudio -D
gpg-agent --daemon --enable-ssh-support --write-env-file /tmp/.gpg-agent-info
```

The script works for `mpd`. The problem is, though, that lines consisting of a command and (multiple) options (and thus, spaces) will not be splitted into fields. Setting field separator IFS to ' ' makes no difference, which I find strange. What is the matter in this case? Thank you!

Edit: As suggested by alvits, a field separation through evaluating `set $line` within the while loop, provides an easy workaround. But why does `read line` no separation in the first place?

Comment: Can you run your script through [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net/), fix those issues and then edit your question? Also, add `--` to `pgrep` (i.e. `pgrep -- "$1"`). Not 100% sure I understand the issue, but sounds like it could be a word splitting problem or some command interpreting `-` as an option.

Comment: Inside `check_process()` insert this line `eval set $1` as the first statement. Using `eval` is ugly but in your case it is the easiest.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be checking as **"pgrep pulseaudio"**. That is, use just the process/daemon name rather than giving the process/daemon name along with the options. I don't have a machine where i can test this now. This you can do by taking the first field from each line(that will be the process/daemon name). Similarly for the second one. One more thing you can try is the **"-f"** option of pgrep. Try n let me know

Comment: You are right. I try to circumvent this by passing only the first argument $1 to pgrep. But that does not work - instead, the whole line is passed.

Answer (score 0):

Got it: `read` needs to know the fields a line should be splitted into. By changing line 6 to

```
 while IFS=' ' read field1 field2
```

field1 will contain the command, while field2 has the options, which can contain spaces again, since anything after field1 belongs to field2.

Comment: Well done, the IFS should normally be ' ' yet it shouldn't hurt